# Object Serialization Issue With Wicket

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-1.6

I am trying to pass a searchService into a Form into Wicket to use.
When I run this with out the searchService being final I get no issues but I have to make it final in order to use it inside the overwritten onSubmit.

```
    final SearchService searchService = new SearchService();

    Form<?> form = new Form("searchForm") {
        public void onSubmit() {
            List<File> results = searchService.getSearchResults();
            info("Found: " + results.size());
        }
    };
```

If I do that I receive an error:

```
org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream$ObjectCheckException: The object type is not Serializable!
A problem occurred while checking object with type: test.service.SearchService
Field hierarchy is:
  2 [class=test.webui.HomePage, path=2]
    private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=[Ljava.lang.Object;]
      private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children[1] [class=org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form, path=2:searchForm]
        private final test.service.SearchService test.webui.HomePage$1.val$searchService [class=test.service.SearchService] <----- field that is causing the problem
```

I'm new to wicket so I'm wondering if there is a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is expected behavior.

Wicket will serialize the whole page. In fact, the whole pageflow.

The error you are seeing is great because it helps you make your application work in a replicated session cluster.

To solve it you have several options. Off the top of my head:

- You could instantiate the SearchService inside the onSubmit form instead of passing it as an attribute.
- You could use some sort of dependency injection. Wicket supports Guice and Spring out of the box. But nothing stops you from using the injector proxies with other dependency injectors.
- You could store the SearchService on the Wicket Application instead of the page. The wicket application is a non-serializable singleton per cluster node, and it is available in the thread.

Comment: So what I am trying to do is this...
SearchService contains functions that helps me query the database.
I have a regular button that will onClick call searchService.addProduct();
And then the submit button that will onClick call searchService.getSearchResults();

If I do the first option, I will not be able to use my searchService variable in the button function.

What would be the best way? The second or third?

I've been reading up on models and not quite understanding them just yet, but will that also help in this situation?

Comment: Just use the form model to store what you need and pass it on on both components. A model is just a over-hyped pointer. From your comment I take SearchService is mutable, eh?. Bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement `Serializable` to your `SearchService` class and declare a variable `serialVersionUID`.

E.g:

```
public class SearchService implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1769512858853931584L;
    //your code
}
```